# Use iOS UIBezierPath in android (using same parameter )

Tags: android, ios, automatic-ref-counting, uibezierpath

I want draw arc on my screen center.

then, i used `UIBezierPath` in ios already..
but i can't use same parameter in android.

help me two ways..

1. In android drawarc using this parameter (`center`, `radius`, `startangle`, `endangle`)
2. Example android `drawArc` on screen center (Using path)

like this..

[image]

Use iOS `UIBezierPath` in android (using same parameter

(`bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:true`) )

Comment: did you got the your solution from below answer ?

Comment: actually, not yet...T.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw in android  on canvas 
there is a method

```
public void drawArc (RectF oval, float startAngle, float sweepAngle, boolean useCenter, Paint paint)
```

where:

**oval** - The bounds of oval used to define the shape and size of the arc

**startAngle** - Starting angle (in degrees) where the arc begins

**sweepAngle** - Sweep angle (in degrees) measured clockwise

**useCenter** - If true, include the center of the oval in the arc, and close it if it is being stroked. This will draw a wedge
paint - The paint used to draw the arc

Sample

```
 canvas.drawArc(rect, yourStartAngle, yourSweepAngle, false,mselectLinePaint);
```

you can also [See this](http://www.cumulations.com/blogs/5/Understanding-Sweep-angle-in-drawArc-method-of-android) for more help

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Use canvas for android for drawing

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: I don't want  answer like this.. T.T
I want Two way answer.

1.In android drawarc method using this parameter (center, radius, startangle, endangle)


2.Example android drawarc on screen center (Using path)